# Rendering different error messages JSON requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have started to experiment with building an API with Rails, what I am interested in getting correct at the moment is getting the correct error messages displayed dependent on the error with the incoming request.

So at the moment I have something simple

```
def create  
  @component = Component.new(component_params)
    if @component.valid?
      @component.save
      render json: { message: 'Successfully Created Component' }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'Unable to create Component' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
end 

def component_params
  json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(JSON.parse(request.body.read))
  json_params.require(:component).permit(:component_name)
end
```

With a validation in my model

```
validates :component_name, presence: true
```

What I want to know is what if a post request comes in with an invalid parameter `component_name_invalid=invalid`

At the moment this will just return the error `unable to create component`, but I would like to be more specific and say `unpermitted parameter supplied`.

Can I return specific messages depending on what validation has failed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make parameters validation using [rails_param](https://github.com/nicolasblanco/rails_param) gem and translate them validation exception to your JSON format.